# C++ DirectX11 Setting elements in the same vector to different positions in the same update loop

Tags: c++, vector

I want to set two elements in my vector to two different positions in the same update run.

At the moment I have:

```
//Set the position of the bullet to the ship if the trigger is pressed
        if ( projectilesNumber % 2 == 0) //Even number bullet
        {
            playerBullets[projectilesNumber]->SetPosition(Vector2(ship->ReturnPosition().x - 20.0f, ship->ReturnPosition().y -  70.0f));
        }

        if ( projectilesNumber % 2 == 1) //Odd number bullet
        {
            playerBullets[projectilesNumber]->SetPosition(Vector2(ship->ReturnPosition().x + 7.0f, ship->ReturnPosition().y -  70.0f));
        }
```

What I want is to have both the even and the odd numbered bullet set to these positions at the same time, at the moment the code runs through the even number bullet, then in the next update loop it goes through the odd numbered bullet and so on.

`playerBullets` is a vector and `projectilesNumber` is an integer.

`projectilesNumber` gets incremented by 1 each time it goes through the end of the code and starts again.

Comment: Other than using "else", what is wrong with the code as it is now?  What do you mean by "at the same time"?  Do you mean do those in one line of code, or run two threads, where one does even and another does odd?

Comment: I mean the code as it is works, but it's not what I am trying to do. I want to set both positions of the even and odd numbered bullets at the same time, instead of it setting them one at a time each update loop and I don't know how to do this. Not sure what you mean by two threads, I am new to C++ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets them "at the same time".  Otherwise you need to clarify what you mean by "same time".  Note the use of else, which eliminates the second test.

```
    if ( projectilesNumber % 2 == 0) //Even number bullet
        playerBullets[projectilesNumber]->SetPosition(Vector2(ship->ReturnPosition().x - 
                                                     20.0f, ship->ReturnPosition().y -  70.0f));
    else
        playerBullets[projectilesNumber]->SetPosition(Vector2(ship->ReturnPosition().x + 
                                                     7.0f, ship->ReturnPosition().y -  70.0f))
```

If what you mean by "same time" is to do this in one line, then you build a mini-table of the values:

```
const float vals[] = {20.0f, 7.0f};
//...
playerBullets[projectilesNumber]->SetPosition(Vector2(ship->ReturnPosition().x - 
                                              vals[projectilesNumber % 2], 
                                              ship->ReturnPosition().y -  70.0f));
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the poor question.  I don't really understand how it knows what vals is though each time it runs through the function? How does it know if it is 20.0f or 7.0f?

Comment: The array at the beginning is initialized before you enter the loop.  If you look at this line `vals[projectilesNumber % 2]`  that is the trick.  If projectilesNumber is even, it picks vals[0], else vals[1] is picked.